# HttpClient.PostAsync return System.IO.Stream as property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have some legacy code that I'm trying to work with and need to return an existing object that contains a **Stream** from an **ApiController**

```
public class LegacyObject
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }       
}
```

API Code

```
public class BindJson : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string rawRequest;
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
        {
            stream.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            rawRequest = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        rawRequest = rawRequest.ToString();
        var obj  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LegacyParameters>(rawRequest.ToString());
        actionContext.ActionArguments["parameter"] = obj;                
     }

}
public class ReportsController : ApiController
{
    [BindJson]
    [HttpPost]
    public LegacyObject ReturnReport([FromBody]LegacyParameters parameter)
    {           
        LegacyObject r = LegacyClass.GetReportStream(parameters);
        return r; //Object properties are correctly set and no errors at this point
    }
}
```

My call to the Api is

```
using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myserver/");

    string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramList);

    var response = httpClient.PostAsync("/api/ReturnReport", new StringContent(contents, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;                                        

}
```

I get a *500 Internal Server Error* on the PostAsync when my LegacyObject.Stream has content. It works when the stream content is null. I'm working locally on my development PC and web server for the API is IIS Express.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means some exception happened in your server code. How can we know it without having any idea  about your server?

Comment: @Eser - Fair point and I should have included. I have update the question.

Comment: Code, what we need...

Comment: What is the content of *contents*? how does your servers code look like?

Comment: @Eser  I have added the API code.

Comment: @L.B The content contains my LegacyParameters and they get passed successfully.

Comment: What's the body of the response?  Normally for debug mode error information is returned (custom errors are off).

Comment: @David - The HttpResponseMessage class does not contain a body property. The StatusCode is System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError

Comment: @user3612921: Does it contain any properties which would hold the body content of the response?  If your server truly isn't returning any information about the error then alternatively I suppose you could debug more on the server.  Such as globally catching exceptions in a base controller.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get more detail on the 500 Internal Server Error, I added this to my projects **WebApiConfig** Register

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger());
```

With this class

```
public class UnhandledExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        var log = context.Exception.ToString();
        //Write the exception to your logs
    }
}
```

The log variable now gives me the detail I need to debug

FYI - The error was a read timeout on my Stream